# AngularJS Switch off input disabled switch on input enabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS and have a switch, I want it to have that if the switch is turned off that my md-input-container is disabled by default. And when I click the switch to on that the md-input-container is enabled again.

What I have right now works a little bit, but when I want to turn the switch off again the md-input-container is still enabled.

My HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <md-switch ng-click="enabled()">
      Online verkoop
  </md-switch>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
    <md-input-container class="md-block">
       <label style="color: #e94e18;">Bezorgkosten (€)</label>
       <input ng-model="bezorgkosten" ng-disabled="disabled">
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
//disable switches
$scope.disabled= true;

$scope.enabled = (function(){
    $scope.disabled = false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$scope.enabled = (function(){
    $scope.disabled = !$scope.disabled;
});
```

You can even get that function off the scope

```
<md-switch ng-click="disabled = !disabled">
  Online verkoop
</md-switch>
```